# How to hide own eBay username from eBay community profile?

Tags: privacy, account-management, ebay, profile, username

How can I hide my eBay username from the public-facing portion of my eBay Community profile?

When I'm logged out and go to the public-facing part of my Community profile, I see my eBay buyer/seller username, feedback score with a link to my feedback profile, and a link to my listings.

How can I make that info private?

Also my eBay Community profile username is the same as my eBay buyer/seller username.

How can I make them different from each other?